# Docker: execute django migration into a db container from inside of the web container

Tags: django, docker, build, gitlab-ci, migrate

Django 2.2.

docker 19.03.2

I run a CI pipeline in gitlab. The stage executes several steps:

First  I start  db container:

```
docker run --name db -p 5432:5432 \
        -e DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<myapp>.settings.postgres -d postgres:9.6
```

Note that I specify a non-default settings file (which contains my db credentials)

Then I check if it worked:

```
docker inspect db
```

> true

Now I build web container with Django 2.2 inside and feed it the DB credentials of the postgres container :

```
docker build --pull -t test_image . \
    --build-arg DB_NAME=<mydbname> \
    --build-arg DB_HOST=db \
    --build-arg DB_USER=<mydbuser> \
    --build-arg DB_PASS=<mydbpassword>
```

Some clarification here: Dockerfile accepts the variables like this:

```
...
ARG DB_NAME
ARG DB_HOST
ARG DB_PASSWORD
ARG DB_USER

ENV DB_NAME=$DB_NAME
ENV DB_HOST=$DB_HOST
ENV DB_PASS=$DB_PASS
ENV DB_USER=$DB_USER
....
```

Now `docker build` runs  `Dockerfile` sequence of many steps and at some point arrives to the Django DB migration:

```
RUN python manage.py migrate --settings <myapp>.settings.postgres
```

That invariably chokes with this error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server:
>   Connection refused    Is the server running on host "db" (127.0.0.1) and
>   accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Which I think means that the name I gave to the postgres container ("db") when it was started does not mean anything inside this (web) container.

I checked the db redentials variables before "migrate" step (just printed with echo) - they all made it ok.

I also made some experiments adding `--add-host=db:127.0.0.1` (and `--add-host=db:localhost`) to both `docker run --name db ...` and `docker build ..` commands, and `--expose=5432` to `docker run --name db ...`, and got the same error.

How do I correctly run "`python manage.py migrate` " from inside of the build (Dockerfile) of web container AGAINST THE DB IN THE DB CONTAINER THAT HAS BEEN STARTED PRIOR TO THIS?

**UPDATE**
At the end I redesigned the system. Migration is executed from .gitlab_ci.yml, not from inside of the container. This way IP address I need I get from "docker inspect -f ..."

Answer (score 0):

you can try creating a network

```
docker network create test_network
```

and pass it while starting both containers

```
docker run --name db -p 5432:5432 -e DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<myapp>.settings.postgres -d --network test_network postgres:9.6
```

Or you can just simply make a docker-compose.yaml file like this and link both containers

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER:'foo'
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD:'foobar'
      - POSTGRES_DB:'foo'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  web:
    image: test_image
    environment:
      DB_NAME: foo
      DB_USER: foo
      DB_PASS: foobar
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and run it with

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Thank you, that's an option if I don't figure it out without that. I never ran docker-compose before from .gitlab-ci.yml, I suspect it involves some prior config.